# very nasty Integral

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

I am looking for a way to deal with concatinations of functions when integrating.
in particular i am trying to integrate the following
$$\int_0^t f(g(h(x)))dx$$ for $$f(x)=x^2\;\;\;\;\;\; g(x)=x-x_*\;\;\;\;\;\;h(x)=\frac{\exp(ax)x_0}{1+\frac{b}{a}(\exp(ax)-1)x_0}$$
Does anyone have any tips? i keep trying substitution but that does not help and i also have a hard time looking for a logarithmic integration ($h$ could be rewritten via a logarithmic term). Can anyon give tips? I don't see any way to apply complex analysis either.

for clearance:
$\int_0^t \left(\frac{\exp(ax)x_0}{1+\frac{b}{a}(\exp(ax)-1)x_0} -x_*\right)^2 dx$

Comment: $$\mathcal{I}_{\space\text{a}}\left(\text{b},x_0,x_*\right):=\int_0^t\frac{x_0\cdot\exp\left(\text{a}\cdot\left(x-x_*\right)^2\right)}{1+x_0\cdot\frac{\text{b}}{\text{a}}\cdot\left(\exp\left(\text{a}\cdot\left(x-x_*\right)^2\right)-1\right)}\space\text{d}t\tag1$$

Comment: @Jan I think that is $\int_0^th(f(g(x)))\ dx$

Comment: Why are you trying to integrate this?

Comment: i want to integrate this in order to get a stabilty property for a nonlinear stochastic filter process. sadly the integral looks like this.

Comment: There is no formula to compute $\int f(g(t))\;dt$ in terms of $\int g(t)\;dt$ and $\int f(t)\;dt$.  In fact, there is no formula for $\int f(t)^2\;dt$ in terms of $\int f(t)\;dt$.